# Route with populate() not working in production but works fine in local

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am populating bugs of user based on ID.
I have followed all steps and able to populate in my local., but when i deploy this code to heroku, it is throwing error.
Posting the necessary code below

Route:

```
let getAllBugs = async (req, res) => {
 
  let user = await userModel.findById(req.user._id)
  console.log("user->" + req.user);
  console.log(req.user)
 await user.populate("userBugs").execPopulate();

  res.send(user.userBugs);
};
```

Models:

```
userSchema.virtual('userBugs', {
  ref: 'Trackers',
  localField:'_id',
  foreignField:'owner'
})
```

```
  owner: {
    type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'users',
  },
```

All other routes are working, so do i have to update anything w.r.t production environment when hitting the above route.
Does it have to do anything with async as all my other routes are not async?

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that there is an issue with GET requests in my postman client. If u ever face this issue, please try from some other client and verify your route.